# generation of multi-level menu

Tags: php, arrays, menu

I have a problem with the generated multi-level menu. I would like each menu level select another color (li class=menucolor). However, I managed to only the first and 2nd level do. I can't separate the second level from the third level. Please help.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`id_parent` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`order` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`title` varchar(255) collate utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);


INSERT INTO `menu` (`id`, `id_parent`, `link`, `order`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 0, index.php, 3, 'Index'),
(3, 1, link1.php, 1, 'Art1'),
(4, 1, link2.php, 2, 'Art2'),
(5, 4, link2.php, 6, 'Other art'),
(6, 4, link2.php, 1, 'Art AAA'),
(7, 4, link2.php, 1, 'Art BBB'),
(8, 4, link2.php, 1, 'Art CCC'),
```

AND CODE:

```
<ul id="menu_left">
<?php
$menuArray = array();
$query = mysql_query('  select id, id_parent, link, order, title
                        from menu
                        order by order asc
              ');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $menuArray[] = array( 'id'           => $row['id'],
                        'id_parent'    => $row['id_parent'], 
                        'link'         => $row['link'],
                        'order'        => $row['order'], 
                        'title'        => $row['title']
              );
}

function menu($id)
{
  global $menuArray;
  $hasChildren = false;
  $resultArray = array();

  if (empty($menuArray))
  {
    return;
  }

  foreach ($menuArray as $value)
  {
    if ($value['id_parent'] == $id)
    {
      $resultArray[] = $value;

    }
  }

  foreach ($resultArray as $value)
  {
    if ($hasChildren === false)
    {
      $hasChildren = true;
      if ($value['id_parent'] == 0)
      {
      $j++
        ?>
        <!-- ul first -->
        <?php
      }
      else
      {
        ?>
       <!-- <ul> -->
        <?php
      }
    }
    if($j=='1') {
    echo '<li class="menucolor0">';
    }
    elseif($j!='1') {
    echo '<li class="menucolor1">';
    }
    ?>
    <a href=<?php echo $value['link']; ?>"><?php echo $value['title']; ?></a> 
    <?php
    menu($value['id']);
    ?> 
    </li>
    <?php
  }
  if ($hasChildren === true)
  {
  <!-- </ul> -->
  }
}

menu(0); 
?>    
        </ul>
```

Comment: Your level and parent definitions in your table to not match Index seems to have level 3 but has no parent, items with ids 5 and 6 have the same parent but different levels! Fix your table definitions first!

Comment: This is my table: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d6id9g15

Comment: Oh, so your `level` column should actually be called `order` instead, that was misleading me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any direct solution to this would be very slow, I suggest you update your table as such:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password',
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

$db->prepare('ALTER TABLE `menu` ADD COLUMN `level` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;')->execute();

$db->prepare('UPDATE `menu` SET `level` = 1 WHERE `id_parent` = 0;')->execute();

$select = $db->prepare('SELECT `id` FROM `menu` WHERE `level` = :level');
$update = $db->prepare('UPDATE `menu` SET `level` = :level WHERE `id_parent` = :parent');

for( $i = 1; $i < 100; $i++ ) {
    $select->execute(array('level' => $i));
    while( ($current = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)) !== false )
        $update->execute(array('level' => $i + 1, 'parent' => $current));
}
```

and here is how you display the menu in the desired order:

```
<?php
// connect to database using PDO
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password',
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));


function createsubmenu( $item )
{
    global $db;
// prepare a query to get subitems of the current $item (those with parent = $item)
    $subsel = $db->prepare('SELECT id, link, title, level  FROM menu WHERE id_parent = :parent ORDER BY `order`');
// run the query
    $subsel->execute(array('parent' => $item));
    $text = '';
// fetch one row at a time, when no more rows are available $i
// will be false and while ends
    while( ($i = $subsel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) !== false ) {
// generate code for the current $item
// will recursively call createsubmenu to add possibly existing subitems
        $text .= '<li class="menucolor' . ($i->level - 1) . '">'
            .'<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($i->link) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($i->title) . '</a>'
            . createsubmenu($i->id) . '</li>';
    }
// there were no items for the current call
    if( $text == '' )
        return '';
// items were found, wrap them in an unordered list
    return '<ul>' . $text . '</ul>';
}

// call the function for toplevel items (the ones having parent 0)
echo createsubmenu(0);
```

don't forget to replace databasename, username and password in both scripts

Comment: ok, thx. It's work. I've one problem with this menu. I wish that there be only selected submenu. Like this: http://awesomescreenshot.com/04cidbte0 (not: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cbidbnb5)

Comment: Edited my answer, added code to display the menu the way I understood you wanted it to the bottom, you should learn to use PDO as well, it will save you a lot of pain from using the deprecated mysql_query and mysql_fetch functions.

Comment: @Wojtek Hope that helps, let me know if it does what you want or I misunderstood it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have to understand.

Comment: Oh, forgot `ORDER BY` in the query, just added it.

Comment: @Wojtek Heavily commented above code, let me know if you understand it now. Also please vote my answer if this actually does what you intended it to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($j=='1') {
echo '<li class="menucolor0">';
}
elseif($j!='1') {
echo '<li class="menucolor1">';
}
```

You're only allowing for two cases, either it equals 1 or it doesn't.

```
switch ($j) {
case 1:
    echo  '<li class="menucolor0">';
    break;
case 2:
     echo '<li class="menucolor1">';
    break;
case 3:
     echo '<li class="menucolor2">';
     break;
default:
     echo '<li class="menucolor0">;
     break;
```

}

Comment: He might want even more levels later, I would suggest `echo '<li class="menucolor' . ($j - 1) . '">'` instead of your whole switch thing, otherwise good answer, you got my vote.

Comment: Yeah I considered that too but it didn't seem he intended to go too deep. If it weren't a menu your answer makes more sense. Heck it probably makes more sense anyway given it's a lot less code lol.

Comment: I noted in my comment on the post itself that he even has level 6 in that table, so I don't know how deep he wants to go.

Comment: The $j takes the value of 1 for the main level and a lack of value for others. I can not just separate the next level. See: http://awesomescreenshot.com/088id9f81 and http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d6id9g15

Comment: Fixed code should be the name of a column: **order** and not **level** (which was confusing)